# if else-works,if else with ternary operator doesn't work

Tags: javascript, if-statement, ternary-operator

I have simple if/else statement,and it works normally,but doesn't work when I replace it with if/else statement using ternary operator.

```
  if (UPorDOWN == -1 ) {
    SEC_IN_VIEW++
  } else{
    SEC_IN_VIEW--
  }
```

That works,but how can I make that work using if/else statement with ternary operator.
I tried this.

```
   (UPorDOWN == -1 ) ? SEC_IN_VIEW++ : SEC_IN_VIEW--
```

**Sorry for this but acctually the problem was in the previous line,which didn't had ";" on the end,but line was to long and it was outside of view and I tottaly forgot to check that.**

Comment: It's working for me in my console. What result do you normally expect, and what's happening when you use the ternary operator?

Comment: BTW I'm using that in for loop,so UPorDown shows which way are sections(SEC) going,(I'm using Math.sign for that),and that should decide if SEC_IN_VIEW should be incremented or decremented on every for loop iteration

Comment: Seems to work just fine

Comment: `using if/else statement with ternary operator` - can you post some code that uses if/else with ternary operator, because all you've posted is some if/else code, and some ternary operator code, no code that uses if/else with ternary operator

Comment: look at the last line,there is ternary operator

Comment: Seeing how this was a typo, I'm voting to close as *can't reproduce*. OP, you could also just delete this question to help keep SO tidy.

Answer (score 0):

Try assignment:

```
SEC_IN_VIEW = (UPorDOWN == -1 ) ? SEC_IN_VIEW+1 : SEC_IN_VIEW-1;
```

OR

```
SEC_IN_VIEW = (UPorDOWN == -1 ) ? SEC_IN_VIEW++ : SEC_IN_VIEW--;
```

Comment: Acctually it works only once ,I mean works only on first for loop iteration

Comment: So I guess there is some logical error. What exactly fails here?